# Why is $E( \langle f(x),f(y) \rangle \langle g(x),g(y) \rangle) \leq E(\lVert g(x) \rVert^2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, probability-theory

Say, $p$ is a probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f,g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be measurable functions such that $E_{x\sim p} \left (\lVert f(x) \rVert_2^2 \right )\leq 1$.

Then, why is $E_{x,y\sim p} \Big (\langle f(x),f(y) \rangle \langle g(x),g(y) \rangle \Big) \leq E_{x\sim p} \left (\lVert g(x) \rVert_2^2 \right )$, where the $x,y$ are sampled independently for the first expectation?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz basically. But there's two Cauchy-Schwarz inequalities here, one at the level of the functions as vector entities in a space with an inner product, the other at the level of the expectations in a probability space.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Aha.. silly me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E_{x,y\sim p}(<f(x),f(y)><g(x),g(y)>)$$ $$ \leq E_{x,y\sim p} \|f(x)\|\|f(y)\| \|g(x)\|\|g(y)\| $$ $$=(E_{x,y\sim p} \|f(x)\|\|g(x))\|) (E_{x,y\sim p} \|f(y)\|\|g(y)\|)$$ $$ \leq \left (\sqrt {E_{x\sim p}(||f(x)\|_2^2)} \sqrt {E_{x\sim p}(||g(x)\|_2^2)}\right)^{2} $$